# Does an android app follow client side/server side architechture with regards to database?

Tags: php, android

I am an android newbie who is coming from PHP background. In PHP basically what happens is that 
all of the database connections happen in php code(server side) and then it later coverts in html code(client side).

From what I have seen in android for database connection, we write a service in php using mysql. And from our Android java class, we make the service call(always aysnc I think), and then when the result comes, we update the UI(kinda like Ajax architecture and gwt).

The system above makes sense to me. I read somewhere that even though using JDBC is not practical on android, it can be still be used. Let' say for example's sake, we want to make the database call through JDBC. In a normal web app, I would put it in a servelet. But in android, we don't have that. All we have is UI widgets code.

So just to the understand the architecture, could someone please explain to me where I would make the JDBC call in the code? or in broader terms does it's architecture differ from traditional client/server side?

Comment: u app hv jdbc db remote or local?

Comment: so u can easily perform operation on that db via service..

Comment: can u come in chat room here -->http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34961/m-t-e-t-n-o , i hv few question to ask

Answer (score 3):

### Like Php:

A brief recap of what you used to do in `PHP` is as follows:

- Connects to `MySQL` server using `PHP`
- Query the server using `PHP` function
- `MySQL` server receives, parse the query and send the results back
- `PHP` parses the response and then you displays (or do anything with) it

`PHP` has built in support for **MySQL** library.

Now in android we have built in support for **SQLite**. But the difference is `SQLite` stores its data on the device itself not on the server.

For database operations same procedure is followed using `SQLite`:

- Using `Android`(Java) activity it connects to `SQLite` database
- A query is sent to database
- `SQLite` engine receives, parses the query and sends the results back
- `Android` activity receives the result and then you can do whatever you want with it

### But, Here comes the issue

This is only good if you want to store the data locally, like saving a users score.

Suppose, you want to have a leader-board in a game you built. Then you can't do it this way, because data is stored locally on all devices. For this we need to have all the users data stored on one/same place.

### The Solution (like~in PHP)

We will save our data on an online server and will retrieve it whenever required. We can connect to any database engine on the server but `MySQL` is fast as compared to others. So, we will use `MySQL` as our database server and connect to it using a `PHP` web service.

That web service will do all (mostly CREATE and READ) database operations for you. This way you can save the data in the server and retrieve it globally whenever you want.

But, how it is done? Here are the steps:

- Create a web service

  - A collection of `PHP` scripts which can read and write, to and from database
  - For security, plug in something like `OAuth` to perform transactions and encrypt data being transferred (*Best will be to write this type of service in a framework*)
- Send READ or WRITE request from `Android` activity to web service
- Web service receives, authorize, parse the request
- Web service then sends the appropriate request to `MySQL` server
- `MySQL` server receive, parse the query and send the results back to web service
- Web service receive, parse the response and send the results back to `Android` activity
- `Android` Activity receives the data and then you can play with it :)

Comment: just as add-on. All of the Android side of the interaction you do in JSON because parsing XML in Android is one of the most annoying tasks possible.

Answer (score 1):

You might have private databases in Android itself without using JSON etc. Just like you used in PHP with MySQL.

You might find lots of tutorials about SQLLite. But, here is official documentation of Google's Android page:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't use JDBC in android. The reason is JDBC is too heavy for mobile.
But you can use built in SqLite support to work with your local sqlite database. It has some limitations comparing to JDBC MySql driver but it should fit your needs.
Usage of SqLite is simple:

- Connect to database
- Send query
- Get your data
- Process data

The only thing you have to remember is that you should not use SqLite in main thread. You may create your own with Thread but the simplest solution is to use AsyncThread.

If you want to make calls to remote MySql database then your way is a bit more complicated

- Write server side code that will handle requests from android and send it to database(e.g. using JSON)
- Send request to remote server from your android device
- Receive server's answer
- Process it

As in above method with SqLite you should do it in a background thread to not to block UI.

Answer (score -2):

-If needed you can use a local database (using SQLite)

-Server/client side in android are similar to any other application: you need a WebService handler which is usually (best practice) an AsyncTask.

Solution: nice and easy... 
Create a .php that does the job for you, parse the result as a json workflow. Use your asynctask to get and parse the result. Add data to your database if needed. You can finally display a nice UI in the onPostExecute method.